# Find with $in clause causing stackoverflow in Mongodb & Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to fetch multiple entries using $in. I'm getting a stackoverflow in the callback even though I have only have 3 records in the db. My function looks like this -

```
 // users is an array
 // callback is function(err, result) 
 function(users, callback) {
      users = db.collection('users');
      users.find({ username: {$in: users }}, function(err, items) {
          // items is a cursor
          items.toArray(callback);
      });
 }
```

Can't seem to figure out what the issue is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your `users` array parameter and the `users` collection variable different names:

```
function(userids, callback) {
    var users = db.collection('users');
    users.find({ username: {$in: userids }}, function(err, items) {
        // items is a cursor
        items.toArray(callback);
    });
}
```

As it is now, you're overwriting the `users` parameter array of ids with the `users` collection.

Comment: Aw damn.. Thanks buddy. Can't believe I spent couple of hours on this